# Priority is not integer in clickup api

Tags: python, clickup-api

I am using [clickuppython](https://github.com/Imzachjohnson/clickupython) to call clickup API. When I set Priority in Clickup dashboard (e.g. High), I get this error

```py
        # Example request | Creating a task in a list
        c = client.ClickUpClient(API_KEY)

        tasks = c.get_tasks(self.list_id, include_closed=True)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROJECT\Clickup\main.py", line 29, in main
    click_up_client.fetch_data()
  File "C:\PROJECT\Clickup\request_manager\clickup\client.py", line 40, in fetch_data
    tasks = c.get_tasks(self.list_id, include_closed=True)
  File "C:\Users\x\.conda\envs\general\lib\site-packages\clickupython\client.py", line 631, in get_tasks
    return models.Tasks.build_tasks(fetched_tasks)
  File "C:\Users\x\.conda\envs\general\lib\site-packages\clickupython\models.py", line 703, in build_tasks
    return Tasks(**self)
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Tasks
tasks -> 2 -> priority
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

This is a part of the result as JSON from postman and clickup API:

```json
          "watchers": [],
            "checklists": [],
            "tags": [],
            "parent": null,
            "priority": {
                "color": "#f8ae00",
                "id": "2",
                "orderindex": "2",
                "priority": "high"
            },
```

as you see, the Priority is a JSON object, not an int.
from the [documentation](https://clickup.com/api/developer-portal/tasks/#setting-priority), it should be:

> Setting priority
> priority is a number that corresponds to the Priorities available in the ClickUp UI. As in the ClickUp UI, priorities cannot be customized. 1 is Urgent 2 is High 3 is Normal 4 is Low

So what is the solution?

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet you have created that is causing the error? It's impossible to tell what is wrong and assist you with just the error message and expected output.

Comment: Instead of passing `priority` to the API call, pass `int(priority)`.

Comment: @AdamDS I post the code

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Clickup documentation](https://clickup.com/api/developer-portal/tasks/) for tasks,

> priority is a number that corresponds to the Priorities available in the ClickUp UI. As in the ClickUp UI, priorities cannot be customized. 1 is Urgent 2 is High 3 is Normal 4 is Low

I am not familiar with that Python library in particular, but it appears you might have to pass one of these integers when setting priority rather than a string. Let me know if this works.